# Its possible to see the sql query that we are doing in browser?

Tags: php, mysql

i have a basic doubt.

i have this example:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin where id =  username='$username' and password = '$password' LIMIT 1");
```

Its possible to see what this sql command is doing in the browser? To see if it is correct..

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't the purpose of doing a query to *see* some result after-all?

Comment: Just assign it to a variable first, and then pass the variable into `mysql_query()`

Comment: You could do `var_dump($sql);` which will probably give you an object statement only.

Comment: You are using a deprecated library (mysql_*).  You should be using either PDO with Mysql or Mysqli

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = "SELECT * FROM admin where id =  username='$username' and password = '$password' LIMIT 1";
echo $a;
$sql = mysql_query($a); // use mysqli instead
```

Answer (score 0):

if you will print the $sql it will print #resurce #4

you need to do:

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM admin where id =  username='$username' and password = '$password' LIMIT 1";

print_r($q);
```

and you see it in the network tab on the console or in the browser if you print your request